# How to Include JAR with resources into APK

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jar, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a maven dependency in my Android project but when the APK is built, all of the resources that the JAR dependency needs are stripped out. For example, I have `somelib.jar` and the maven pom packages in `someCLibrary.so` and `anotherCLibrary.so` into the JAR under the structure

```
com/
   package/
      ...
x86/
   someCLibrary-i686.so
   anotherCLibrary-i686.so
arm64-v8a/
   someCLibrary-aarch64.so
   anotherCLibrary-aarch64.so
```

In `build.gradle` I have

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   implementation `com.package...`
}
```

I know android typically packages `*.so` files under the `lib` directory of the APK, however it seems like when you pull in a JAR it can be expected that it has dependencies that it relies on and Android would have a way of recognizing that and not strip them out.

I would rather not have to rewrite the maven dependency as an Android package. I also looked at Fat JAR files but I'd rather not get tied to that if I don't have to because the maintainer is no longer working on that package.

Comment: Your question would be much easier to answer if would just name the library you are trying to use and the dependencies that make problems. The more precise the question is the better can be the answer...

Comment: This is a proprietary package